# GitLab CI/CD for vue.js application and Node API

Tags: vue.js, gitlab, continuous-integration

how to edit the .gitlab-ci.yml file in order to correctly execute the CI/CD pipeline on behalf of a vue.js application?

Comment: what have you tried so far, did you take a look at the official blog from gitlab: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2017/09/12/vuejs-app-gitlab/ - if you tried this what is not working?

Answer (score 1):

A `.gitlab-ci.yml` should be part of your repository, at the root folder of said repo.

See for example "[How to use GitLab CI/CD for Vue.js](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2017/09/12/vuejs-app-gitlab/)" (2017, so some details may have changed since then)
Or the 2020 "[How to auto deploy a Vue application using GitLab CI/CD on Ubuntu 18.04](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-auto-deploy-a-vue-application-using-gitlab-ci-cd-on-ubuntu/)"

In both case, you can directly edit the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, add, commit and push.

> Create a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file at the root of your repo.
> GitLab will check for this file when new code is pushed.
> If the file is present, it will define a **[pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/index.html)**, executed by a **[GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/)**.